# use variable inside an array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, variables

I would like to know how I can access the `var randomnumber` inside that `cubesmixed`-Array
This is the code:

```
var cubesmixed = [paper.rect(randomnumber, randomnumber, 0, 0), 
                  paper.rect(randomnumber, randomnumber, 0, 0), 
                  ... going on till over 100]; 
var randomnumber;
for(var i = 0; i < 143; i++) {
var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*2000);
    cubesmixed[i].animate({ width: 25, height: 25 }, 500, "bounce");
    console.log(i);
}
```

inside that array the value of randomnumber is 0. How can I do this?

Cheers

Comment: What do you mean 'inside that array the value of randomnumber is 0'? You mean that raphael is generating rectangles at 0,0? Surely that'll be because randomnumber == undefined when the array is defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare `randomnumber` twice, both times *after* using it in the `cubesmixed` declaration. So currently each time you actually use `randomnumber` it'll be `undefined`. Currently you set `randomnumber` equal to a randomly generated number inside your `for` loop, but you don't actually use it within the loop.

If your actual goal to create an array of 143 items each of which have different random coordinates then you can do this:

```
var cubesmixed = []; 
var cube;
for(var i = 0; i < 143; i++) {
  cube = paper.rect(Math.floor(Math.random()*2000), Math.floor(Math.random()*2000), 0, 0);
  cube.animate({ width: 25, height: 25 }, 500, "bounce");
  cubesmixed.push(cube);
}
```

On the other hand if you just want all the items to have the same coordinates as each other move your current line:

```
var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*2000);
```

...from inside the loop to *before* the `cubesmixed` declaration.

Comment: thank you very much. You sir got exactly what I wanted to do (yeah I removed that second `randomnumber` immediatly to stop confusing). Your first example was the way to go, thanks!